# Selenuim WebDriver bug? ChromeDriver not focusing on field when setting value?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been struggling with this one today;

I have an input field that has some custom JavaScript that displays a 'hint' piece of text when the field's value is empty and the user has not clicked on the field (i.e. focused on it). Otherwise it disappears.

As of a few days ago the following code worked fine with the input field with this hint JS:

```
WebDriver driver = chromeDriver;
WebElement fieldWithHint = driver.findElement(By.id("myField"));

fieldWithHint.sendKeys(newValue);
```

Today it doesn't work (since I have restarted my machine) - the hint JS gets very confused and on entering the text, and moving to the next field, then displays the text as the hint.

I have just discovered that the following does still work:

```
WebDriverBackedSelenium driverWrapper = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(chromeDriver, "http://localhost/");
WebElement fieldWithHint = chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("myField"));

driverWrapper.type(fieldWithHint.getAttribute("name"), newValue);
```

I am using WebDriver for Java (version 0.9.7376), the latest ChromeDriver (2.9) and Chrome version 34.0.1847.116 m.

I wonder whether restarting my computer, and hence restarting Chrome, has updated it and caused this issue.

Has anyone else seen this? Is it a known issue?

I have tried first clicking in the field to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had a related issue since upgrading to v34.

I have a page of input fields, each linked to an onblur event, which I trigger via a tab out of the input.

before the upgrade, this worked fine, now tabbing out of the last field, doesn't trigger the event.

A manual tab takes focus to the address bar, where as a selenium tab goes to the first element in the DOM. I have not yet performed the same investigation on v33 nor have I raise a defect.

I know this is linked to the upgrade as it was failing on Grid nodes which had auto updated but was fine locally until I upgraded

*****EDIT*****

Managed to reproduce and raised with Chromedriver (https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=762)

My issue is that if you send :tab and this results in focus being shifted to address bar, then focus does not get reapplied to elements even if you interact with them.

Comment: Confirming my suspicion! This is annoying though - always seem to have issues when Chrome gets upgraded :(

Comment: I have created a simple HTML page to try and replicate this but I think it must be a bit more complicated then my original theory.